# javascript set interval run as separate thread?

Tags: javascript

I want to use a timer as a fallback in case I end up in an infinite loop. It seems that set interval is the right way to do this. However, it's not working for me.

From my research, it seems like setInterval should run in a separate thread in the background, but I don't see it.

Why is this behavior happening? And how do I solve this?

```
var time = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){time++;}, 1000);
while (true) {
    //stuff done
    if (time >= 5) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Browser javascript runs in a single thread. So if you perform something that takes too long - it will freeze browser.

See John Resig article for further details: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

After you read that article you'll get that your `setInterval` callback queued to be run in 1000ms after now but only after the current code is finished. It cannot finish though, because of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

**zerkms** has the correct answer. But I would add that [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) are a way to get some multi-threaded-ish behavior from client side javascript.

```
var worker = new Worker('my_task.js');
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
 console.log("Called back by the worker!\n");
};
```

The worker runs in a background thread, and you can exchange messages and subscribe to events. It's pretty nifty.

Comment: Thanks for the web workers link. Do I read correctly that the message from the worker has to wait until the infinite loop finishes (= does not solve OP's issue)?

Answer (score 2):

As has been already said - the callback to `setInterval` doesn't run until the infinite loop finishes. To do what you are trying to achieve - without using web workers - you have to check the time from the loop itself:

```
var start = Date.now();
while((Date.now() - start) < 5000){
  ...
}
```