# How do threads take up stack space?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, memory-management

So to start and avoid confusion, the code below is what sparked my thought, it doesn't necessarily have much to do much with my question except for an example to explain where my question is coming from.

I was just looking at some code in javascript here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/pvk6p/

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, .1);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

The person seemed to use recursion to make a stop watch, in timer and add.

If I do it recursively, by changing this function to this:

```
function timer() {
    add();
}
```

it takes up stack space, and eventually breaks, stops some where under 3:00:00.

But then I realized in the original code they used setInterval(), which just creates a separate thread then ends the thread, releasing the stack space. The code just does this repeatedly which is why the stack doesn't seem to overflow.

What I am having a hard time understanding is how does this work on a lower level? In one of my courses I took, I was required to make my own memory allocator(which i understand takes up heap space), but we never had to worry about threads and am wondering how I will do it with this.

So lets say I have a thread, and then the kernel switches to another thread, and then another, then one thread ends and another one begins, I am assuming there  is going to be gaps in the stack in between threads ending and being created, correct?. I read in another post (more related to java, not sure if programming language matters) that each thread takes its own space on the stack. So I was wondering, each time I make a thread, does it just fill in gaps like a memory allocator does? What if a thread ends up taking up too much space? Does the program know to realloc memory somewhere else? Am I thinking of this wrong?

Comment: Part of this is language dependent. But I don't think SetInterval uses a thread, it uses events. I don't think JS has (real) threads.

Comment: Your assumption(s) are wrong, the question isn't really answerable. Not without a complete teardown first.

Comment: Is that why there wasn't a stack overflow? Because it's an event? Also what do you mean by doing "a complete teardown"? Is there something I can do in my own time to see how this works on the stack?

Comment: This is not worth an answer, but [here is a great presentation on  the event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) (also a fun watch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded. See, for example, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504811](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504811/javascript-set-interval-run-as-separate-thread). The main and the single javascript thread has one queue of ready tasks, and one queue of timed tasks. It cycles over the first queue until it is empty, then over the second queue until all timed tasks with exceeded time limit are executed, and the sleeps until new ready task appear, or time comes of some timed tasks.

Expression `setTimeout(add, .1)` just adds a task to the queue of timed tasks. It will be executed when the `.1` timeout exceeded, and the main thread is able to execute next tasks.